# Multiple Stepper Motors in One Shield?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, shields

[image]

I need to construct 4 reactors for an experiment requiring mixing. We want to automate the mixing and at the same time reduce cost. can we connect multiple stepper motors with 5 or 6 wires on one shield version 2?

Comment: Please clarify: what shield model are you using, what stepper motors do you intend to use?

Comment: Is the picture related to question? I can see one 4-wire stepper motor only.

Comment: The board shown looks like it can handle two steppers, as a stepper requires two H bridges (if bipolar, or at least their low side switches if unipolar), so could replace the two PMDC motors requiring one each.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the shield you can connect an external powersource through mosfets or transistors (Depending on the size of the steppermotor).

But if it is smaller motors with a 12v powersource, i really don't se why you would do that, since stepper motor controllers cost about $2-$4 each. Being cost effective i think that writing this question would cost more than actually just go and buy 6-8 controllers. (Don't buy the shield ones, they are overly expensive)